# Is there any way how to use Java window and input with Ogre3D and c++?

Tags: java, c++, opengl, ogre3d

I'm not very familiar with wrapping between Java and C++. But i need to wrap Java window input to c++ and get window context, that i assign to ogre. I know it's possible, because Ogre4J uses something similar.

*"Use Ogre4j" isn't answer.*

Comment: What about *"Look into the source-code of Ogre4J, since it is open source"*? Here you go: http://ogre4j.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ogre4j/trunk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tried it because JOGL was easier to use but [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/opengl.aspx), you have an example how to use opengl directly with Java. That should be similar with OGRE. I guess.
Or you could look at Ogre4j and see how they get the native context from the Java window.